Detect a line with a certain width from an image using OpenCV
I have an image of pixels (1023 x 768). I would like to detect the line in that image, find its angle and position.
I am working with C# and the package OpenCVSharp, but the language isn't of concern.
I convert the image to binary using a threshold (threshold = 60, maxVal = 255). I get something like this: 
Here's a histogram of the RGB values. I found that the threshold 60 to 100 work nicely.
I apply a probabilistic Hough transform on this to get the lines: 
I would prefer a single line being detected, instead of multiple lines.
Among other things, I've also tried this with better results: Apply threshold -> Morphological opening -> Canny Edge Detection -> HoughP  transform 
I can detect the edge, which is fine. What I would rather have is to detect the thicker complete line segment from the image. That, I believe, would give me a more accurate description of the angle it makes with the horizontal axis.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline

Perhaps, minAreaRect() can be used.

@fana That was a good directive. Thanks! It semi-works. The line in the image after thresholding isn't continuous, so I a smaller area is bound by the rectangle, but enough for me to get an angle (which I was also able to get with HoughLinesP, but this looks more accurate.

How about you try Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the binary image?
PCA detects the contour of the line and its orientation.
For a better result, I would try to fill the speckles in the binary image first e.g using Dilation (morphology) before using PCA.
Here is the link to the docu about PCA in OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html
